# Synchronizing Signal messenger chat history from iPad to Android

Tags: signal-private-messenger

Some time ago I added Signal to my iPad and without ado it fetched the complete chat history from my Android phone.

Now I had to reset my Android phone, and assuming the other way would work as well, I didn't create a backup.

Turns out: the respective option is missing under Account. Similarly, on the iPad, there is no option to backup everything.

Can this be done: synchronize the chat history of the Signal app on the iPad to a reinstalled Signal app on Android?

This is not what works for me: https://cight.co/backup-signal-ios-jailbreak/.

Comment: According to the [Signal Support](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007059752-Backup-and-Restore-Messages#not_supported), "*switched between Android and iOS*" is not supported, so it's actually kind of surprising that it worked for you for the first time.  (Note: I've never used Signal, so I don't know how it works)

Comment: That was not a switch, but an "add (connect) another device". Maybe it does not work the other way since my iPad has no SIM and the account is bound to the phone number.